# Response.AppendHeader to refresh the page not working in iis

Tags: asp.net, iis-7

I have used the following method to redirect to the home page. Its working in my local iis, but its not working in my production server. Anybody know why its happening like this.

```
Response.AppendHeader("Refresh", "10; URL=~/Default.aspx");
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems the problem in the `URL` parameter. You use the root operator (the tilde `~`) there which should be resolved on the server-side (otherwise client-side won't be able to resolve it) by using [VirtualPathUtility.ToAbsolute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms150160.aspx) method. So changing your code to:

```
Response.AppendHeader(
    "Refresh", 
    string.Format("10; URL={0}", VirtualPathUtility.ToAbsolute("~/Default.aspx"))
);
```

should solve the problem.

Comment: That didnt help. But I found the problem. Its with the Application pool. When I use ASP.NET v4.0 Classic it works. But I cant use Classic pool because it gives an authentication error.